# Why does a vertical scrollbar appear when using inline-flex and min-height: 100% while a horizontal scrollbar is present in Edge?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, microsoft-edge

Here's a pen illustrating the issue: http://codepen.io/derrikcurran/pen/XNmEOZ

The browsers I'm worried about for now are Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.

I have a tree of 3 divs; #grandparent > #parent > #child. If #grandparent has `overflow: auto` and #parent has `display: inline-flex` and `min-height: 100%`, it seems to work well in all 3 browsers. However, if #child is wider than #parent, a horizontal scrollbar appears on #grandparent (as expected and desired) and, only in Edge, a vertical scrollbar appears as well.

It seems that the minimum height calculation in Edge is not taking the height of the horizontal scrollbar into account. In fact, Edge's horizontal scrollbar is 12px tall and `min-height: calc(100% - 12px)` solves the problem.

Is there some way to work around this without useragent sniffing or Javascript? Is it a bug with Edge? To be clear, I need #grandparent to scroll in both directions, but only when #child is taller than #parent.

I'd like to point out that this does **not** appear to be caused by the well known IE11 flexbox/min-height issue described here: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802625/

Answer (score 0):

```
  #grandparent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Your solution */
    overflow-y: auto; /*Other half */
}
```

I fixed your overflow, so the page doesn't scroll.
If you want no scroll bars use "Hidden" for both.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually do need the vertical scrollbar when #child becomes taller than #parent. I'll update my question.